# Compare previous state to new one in React Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I want to try don't spread 'dispatch' if state the same like previous one. 
The problem that my 'state' alway contains default value.

```
const initialState = {
  pending: false,
  fetched: false,
  data: {
    playAndPayAllowed: false,
    sections: {},
    allowedSectionsCount: 0
  }
}

function isPreviousStateEqualToNew(oldState, newState) {
   return JSON.stringify(oldState) === JSON.stringify(newState);
}

export default function shopConfig(state = initialState, action) {
   switch (action.type) {
      case SHOP_CONFIG_PENDING:
        return {
            ...state,
            pending: true,
            data: {
                playAndPayAllowed: false,
                sections: {},
                allowedSectionsCount: 0
            },
            error: false
        }
     case SHOP_CONFIG_SUCCESS:
        if (isPreviousStateEqualToNew(state.data, action.payload)) {
            return;
        }

        const playAndPayAllowed = action.payload.playAndPayAllowed;
        const sections = action.payload.sections || [];
        const allowedSectionsCount = Object.values(sections).filter(item => item);

        return {
            ...state,
            pending: false,
            data: {
                playAndPayAllowed,
                sections: sections,
                allowedSectionsCount: allowedSectionsCount.length
            },
            error: false
        }
    default:
        return state;
}
```

}

The expectation was to see old state in 'state' variable, but 'state' always equal to 'initialState'.

Comment: why don't you just store the previous state in Redux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in my SHOP_CONFIG_PENDING action. It was dispatched every time I perform 'getShopConfig' (SHOP_CONFIG_SUCCESS) and was clearing previous state.

```
 switch (action.type) {
  case SHOP_CONFIG_PENDING:
    return {
        ...state,
        pending: true,
        data: {
            playAndPayAllowed: false,
            sections: {},
            allowedSectionsCount: 0
        },
        error: false
    }
```

So I've deleted field 'data' from SHOP_CONFIG_PENDING and it's become possible to see old state in SHOP_CONFIG_SUCCESS.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see what's the problem or I've got it wrong, just return the unchanged state:

```
if (isPreviousStateEqualToNew(state.data, action.payload)) {
            return state;
        }
```

Comment: so that's a problem, 'state' equal to 'initialState', it doesn't hold an old state.

Comment: @Pasha I'm afraid I don't understand